# Raspberry Pi Chromium Browser freeze after video playback

Tags: chromium

I have a very simple html page, directly running from file (file:///home/pi/Desktop/myfile.html), which infinitely replays a video anytime it ends.

- **Device:** Raspberry Pi 3 Model B + 16GB SD Card
- **OS:** Linux raspberrypi 4.9.80-v7+ #1098 SMP Fri Mar 9 19:11:42 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
- **Browser:** Chromium 72.0.3626.121 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 9.3

The videos I'm playing are very short (about 3 seconds), and bitrate of around 5Mbps.

Here's my js script:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var videoUrl = 'video_3s.mp4';
    var videoTag = document.getElementById('video_place');

    function playVideo() {
        videoTag.src = videoUrl;
    }

    videoTag.oncanplay = function () {
        videoTag.play();
    };
    videoTag.onended = function () {
        playVideo();
    };

    playVideo();
};
```

After about 40 iterations, chromium randomly freezes during the video playback. No errors thrown into console. OS keeps running smoothly though.
If launching chromium from the terminal, I get a 'Bus error' message before forcing the browser to close.

I've tried increasing gpu memory to 256MB and swap size to 1GB, but I'm getting the same behavior.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a browser to play a video? Why not use 'omxplayer'?

Comment: @CoderMike It's a requirement from a bigger project, The script there is just a sample to replicate the issue of the video freezing.

Comment: But where is the problem with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It only happens on the pi. Granted, it could also have something to do with Raspbian itself.

Comment: Please clarify: Is chromium frozen? Or the page inside chromium?